# Use the aggregate() function with dates linking to another specific value in another column

Tags: r

Is it possible to use the aggregate() function in R for dates in the form of 10/20/2016 (MM/DD/YYYY) that link to a specific value in another variable column?  If so, I need to look at the most recent date and delete the earliest ones.

For example,

```
1 Date
A 10/20/2016
A 10/25/2016
A 11/01/2016
B 11/02/2016
B 11/02/2016
B 11/08/2016
```

would become

```
1 Date
A 11/01/2016
B 11/08/2016
```

Just to be clear, the higher month is clearly the most recent in this case, not necessarily the highest number for the day value (They are all from the same year so that is not a concern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Dates are `Dates`,  you can do this with aggregate.

```
## Create test data set
df = read.table(text="ID Date
A 10/20/2016
A 10/25/2016
A 11/01/2016
B 11/02/2016
B 11/02/2016
B 11/08/2016",
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df$Date = as.POSIXct(df$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y" )

aggregate(df$Date, by=list(df$ID), FUN=max)
  Group.1          x
1       A 2016-11-01
2       B 2016-11-08
```